# How to change count after certain value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write a code in Excel that basically counts multiplies valueA by 5 when ValueA<=15. Once valueA surpasses 15 (therefore ValueA>15), it will the multiply ValueA by 9 for the remaining amount value. For example, if ValueA=20, 1-15 will be multiplied by 5, and the 16-20 will be multiplied by 9, to give the total amount.

Can anybody else out with this?

So far, I have:

```
=IF(AND(A2="LR",B2<=15),B2*5, IF(AND(A2="LR",B2>16....
```

not sure how to finish off!

Comment: So with A=20, what is the final output value?

Comment: And what does LR and LP have to do with the question?

Comment: If A=20, the final value would be 120. 5x15=75, plus 9x5=45. LR is the first condition as ValueA column has multiple values. Thanks!

Comment: `=MAX(0,(A1-15)*9)+MIN(A1,15)*5`  Where A1 is the cell in which 20 exists

Comment: Thanks Scott, is there any way to make the code so that it can automatically make these calculations whenever the  value in ValueA is greater thank 15?

Comment: It does.  The same formula will make 5 = 25 and 30 = 210.  There is no need for a second formula.  That one handles all numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(AND(A2="LR",B2<=15),B2*5, IF(AND(A2="LR",B2>15),B2*9-75, ... Whatever value you want if A2 doesn't equal LR))
```